# Is it absolutely unacceptable to change tense in the middle of a sentence?

Tags: tenses

For example:

> I probably wasn't paying attention because I was doing things I'm not used to.

If the *I'm not* is changed to past tense (*I wasn't*), it sounds like I might be used it now, even though I'm not.

Answer (score 2):

The present tense shows that the things you were doing at the time are things that you are not used to doing generally. The past tense would show that things you were doing at the time were things that you were not used to doing up to, and including, that time.